# Can we fire a sql query with multiple where IN clause , if yes how does it work?

Tags: sql, where-in

A query of the format `select * from student where id in(1,2,3,4)` works like

```
select * from student where id=1;
select * from student where id=2;
select * from student where id=3;
select * from student where id=4;
```

*This is what I know to the best of my knowledge.*

**Now I want to fire a query with multiple WHERE IN CLAUSE**

```
SELECT    Count(*) NO_OF_PO, QUANTITY FROM    INTER_DEFECT idp
WHERE    DEFECT_ID IN(1,2,3) 
AND    PO_NUMBER IN (4,5,6)  
AND    SUPP_ID IN (7,8,9)  
AND    LINE_NO IN (10,11,12)    
AND    RECEIPT_NO IN(13,14,15)
```

I want this to fire like this in reality

```
SELECT    Count(*) NO_OF_PO, QUANTITY FROM    INTER_DEFECT idp
WHERE    DEFECT_ID =1
AND    PO_NUMBER =4
AND    SUPP_ID = 7
AND    LINE_NO = 10
AND    RECEIPT_NO=13

 SELECT    Count(*) NO_OF_PO, QUANTITY FROM    INTER_DEFECT idp
    WHERE    DEFECT_ID =2
    AND    PO_NUMBER =5
    AND    SUPP_ID = 8
    AND    LINE_NO = 11
    AND    RECEIPT_NO=14
```

etc etc.

So you see the **Parameter order should not change** like

DEFECT_ID =1 should fire with PO_NUMBER =4 for example

`DEFECT_ID =1 AND PO_NUMBER =4 ....`

And 
 DEFECT_ID =2 should fire with PO_NUMBER =5 for example

`DEFECT_ID =2 AND PO_NUMBER =5 ....`

**Is this possible in Oracle or any other Database ?**

Comment: Your query will get the all the results of your `IN` values cross product.

Comment: Just add ORDER BY DEFECT_ID to the original query?

Comment: @CoderofCode So that means all permutation and combination of the fields in the IN clause right ? How do I avoid the cross product ?

Comment: @jarlh How does `Order by` is going to achieve what OP wants ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Oliver I don't think this is possible without using a stored procedure that takes the different `in` predicates as parameters and parses them to build a query.

Comment: @jarlh Could you please provide the query in the answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle supports `in` clauses with multiple expressions.  That is, you can do:

```
SELECT Count(*) NO_OF_PO, QUANTITY
FROM INTER_DEFECT idp
WHERE (DEFECT_ID, PO_NUMBER, SUPP_ID, LINE_NO, RECEIPT_NO) IN
       ( (1, 4, 7, 10, 13), (2, 5, 8, 11, 14), (3, 6, 9, 12, 15) );
```

Not all databases support this construct.  Normally, you would just use `AND` and `OR`:

```
WHERE (DEFECT_ID = 1 and PO_NUMBER = 4 . . . ) OR
      (DEFECT_ID = 2 and PO_NUMBER = 5 . . . ) OR
      (DEFECT_ID = 3 and PO_NUMBER = 6 . . . )
```

Or use `join` with a CTE or subquery that has the right values.

Comment: Is there anything similar to  `multiple expressions` in sql server ?

Comment: @CoderofCode the closest to this in SQL Server (2008 and later) is to `INNER JOIN` to a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx) - e.g. `INNER JOIN (VALUES (1, 4, 7, 10, 13), (2, 5, 8, 11, 14), (3, 6, 9, 12, 15)) AS tvc (DEFECT_ID, PO_NUMBER, SUPP_ID, LINE_NO, RECEIPT_NO) ON tvc.DEFECT_ID = idp.DEFECT_ID AND tvc.PO_NUMBER = idp.PO_NUMBER ...`

Comment: @CoderofCode . . . SQL Server does not support this syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Well I would like to go for a generic way of doing it using AND OR. Gordon could you please tell if I  use the AND OR method for about 55 to 100 sets of values like (X AND Y) OR (P AND Q) like this for 100 times **HOW SLOW WOULD SUCH A QUERY BE?** Or would be slow at all ?

Comment: @Oliver . . . It would probably require  a full table scan.  The use of a "table" (CTE, subquery, or `values()` clause) would allow the use of indexes, if they are available.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from student where id in(1,2,3,4)
```

works as

```
select * from student where id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3 or id = 4
```

as for your 2nd question, try this

```
SELECT    Count(*) NO_OF_PO, QUANTITY FROM    INTER_DEFECT idp
WHERE    
(DEFECT_ID =1
AND    PO_NUMBER =4
AND    SUPP_ID = 7
AND    LINE_NO = 10
AND    RECEIPT_NO=13
or
DEFECT_ID =2
AND    PO_NUMBER =5
AND    SUPP_ID = 8
AND    LINE_NO = 11
AND    RECEIPT_NO=14)
```

Answer (score 0):

if u have data of DEFECT_ID, PO_NUMBER ,SUPP_ID,LINE_NO,RECEIPT_NO. in a table
then you can do like this
execute this query and copy the total result and paste it in your query window.
You will get the script

```
SELECT  
'SELECT    Count(*) NO_OF_PO, QUANTITY FROM    INTER_DEFECT idp
WHERE  DEFECT_ID =' +DEFECT_ID+
' AND PO_NUMBER = '+PO_NUMBER +
' AND SUPP_ID=' +SUPP_ID+
' AND LINE_NO='+LINE_NO +
' AND RECEIPT_NO='+ RECEIPT_NO

FROM INTER_DEFECT
```

This is so wierd but it will gives your answer

---

Answer (score 0):

With multiple WHERE ... IN like you show, you take all combination about the IN (....) ids.

If you need to take DEFECT_ID =1 WHERE PO_NUMBER =4 ... you need to do something like

```
SELECT    Count(*) NO_OF_PO, QUANTITY FROM    INTER_DEFECT idp
WHERE    ( DEFECT_ID =1  AND    PO_NUMBER =4  AND    SUPP_ID = 7 AND LINE_NO = 10 AND    RECEIPT_NO=13)
OR (DEFECT_ID =2   AND    PO_NUMBER =5   AND    SUPP_ID = 8   AND    LINE_NO  = 11    AND    RECEIPT_NO=14) ...
```